Traefik and C# API: Redirect traffic to specific ports
I host a swarm with Traefik, Portainer and some APIs, in this case, a C# API. I am unable to access my URL without the port, even though the traefik tags on API docker-compose are supposedly correct. Thanks in advance for your help!
The Traefik node has following file docker-compose.yaml.
version: "3.7"
services:

## --------------------------- ORION --------------------------- ##

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.11.2
    command:
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--providers.docker.swarmMode=true"
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.network=ConexxoHubNet" ## Nome da rede interna
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent=true"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--entrypoints.web.transport.respondingTimeouts.idleTimeout=3600"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencryptresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencryptresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencryptresolver.acme.storage=/etc/traefik/letsencrypt/acme.json"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencryptresolver.acme.email=brunopeixoto@suasvendas.com" ## Email para receber as notificações
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--log.format=common"
      - "--log.filePath=/var/log/traefik/traefik.log"
      - "--accesslog=true"
      - "--accesslog.filepath=/var/log/traefik/access-log"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-https.redirectscheme.permanent=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=Host(`{host:.+}`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=web"
        - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-https@docker"
        - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.priority=1"
    volumes:
      - "vol_certificates:/etc/traefik/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        mode: host
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        mode: host
    networks:
      - MySwarmNet ## Nome da rede interna

## --------------------------- ORION --------------------------- ##

volumes:
  vol_shared:
    external: true
    name: volume_swarm_shared
  vol_certificates:
    external: true
    name: volume_swarm_certificates

networks:
  MySwarmNet: ## Nome da rede interna
    external: true
    attachable: true
    name: MySwarmNet ## Nome da rede interna

Likewise, the portainer file docker-compose.yaml is below:
version: "3.7"
services:

## --------------------------- ORION --------------------------- ##

  agent:
    image: portainer/agent:latest ## Versão do portainer

    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes:/var/lib/docker/volumes

    networks:
      - MySwarmNet ## Nome da rede interna

    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints: [node.platform.os == linux]

## --------------------------- ORION --------------------------- ##

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
    command: -H tcp://tasks.agent:9001 --tlsskipverify

    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - portainer_data:/data

    networks:
      - MySwarmNet ## Nome da rede interna

    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`portainer.conexxohub.com.br`)" ## Dominio da aplicação
        - "traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls.certresolver=letsencryptresolver"
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.service=portainer"
        - "traefik.docker.network=ConexxoHubNet" ## Nome da rede interna
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.priority=1"

## --------------------------- ORION --------------------------- ##

networks:
  MySwarmNet: ## Nome da rede interna
    external: true
    attachable: true

volumes:
  portainer_data:
    external: true
    name: portainer_data

Finally, after I push the API image to Docker Hub, I push the following file docker-compose.yaml on Portainer. The domain here is not functional, which requires a bit of mind stretching. As you can see, the port 8081 is the accessible port. However, when I try to access example.com, the only way to access the endpoints is by URL http://example.com:8081/valid-route. I want to make it also available for https and without the port requirement. What is necessary to do so?
version: '3.3'

services:
  api:
    image: dockerhub-image-name/image-name
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production  
    deploy:
        mode: replicated
        replicas: 1
        placement:
          constraints:
            - node.role == manager
        labels:
          - traefik.enable=true
          - traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`example.com`)
          - traefik.http.services.api.loadbalancer.server.port=8081
          - traefik.http.routers.api.service=cadvisor
          - traefik.http.routers.api.tls.certresolver=letsencryptresolver
          - traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=websecure
          - traefik.http.routers.api.tls=true
    networks:
      - MySwarmNet

networks:
  MySwarmNet:
    external: true


loadbalancer.server.port=8080 should be set to the Docker container internal port, as Traefik usually connects via the Docker network. So ports: is not relevant in that context.
I would not use ports: at all for target services, as it makes them available on external ports, potentially circumventing any Traefik security middleware.

It means, you recommend to both remove the ports target and set 8081 to 8080, correct?

Remove ports: - "8081:8080" and set traefik.http.services.api.loadbalancer.server.port=8080.
